# View inside toast

Tags: android, toast

I want to make a toast in which I have put EditText and a button ..but I can't type anything inside EditText neither I can click the button how to write inside EditText that viewed by the toast..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button New=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        final Toast t=new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        New.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            ListView l=new ListView(getApplication());
            l.setAdapter(new badp(getApplicationContext()));

            t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);

            t.setView(l);
            t.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
            }
        });


    }
    public class badp extends BaseAdapter
    {

        Context context;
        private badp(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.context=context;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 1;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LinearLayout l=new LinearLayout(context);
            Button b1=new Button(context);
            b1.setText("Save");
            EditText ed=new EditText(context);
            ed.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
         //   LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams();
           //     ed.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                ed.setWidth(5);
                ed.setEms(10);


            l.addView(ed);
            l.addView(b1);

            return l;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably use a Dialog instead of a Toast.

Dialog is designed for more interactive pop-ups, where-as a toast is really designed to display a quick text message.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think you should use a toast for this kind of user interface. If you look at the documentation it says:

> A toast notification is a message that pops up on the surface of the window. It only fills the amount of space required for the message and the user's current activity remains visible and interactive. The notification automatically fades in and out, and does not accept interaction events.

[Toast Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

What you want is probably a  [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)